# Can I check the number of digits in solidity?

Tags: solidity

Can I check the number of digits in solidity?
I'd live to validate input by ethereum. Can't I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function numDigits(int number) returns (uint8) {
    uint8 digits = 0;
    //if (number < 0) digits = 1; // enable this line if '-' counts as a digit
    while (number != 0) {
        number /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489873